# converting mp3 to mp4

Tags: video, audio, mp3, mp4

I need to convert mp3 files into mp4 or any other video formats, with blank images; so that I can play it on any video player or upload it on youtube. 
I don't want to use the readily available softwares(I will have to manually convert each file using the software), but I need a way to code it which would perform the entire conversion automatically.

Any thoughts on how I can go about doing this? Thanks.

Comment: `ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -shortest -b 1000k -acodec copy output.mp4`

Comment: See http://superuser.com/a/700471/64857

Comment: thanks @MartinThoma

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check FFMPEG. the biggest problem with it is to build it. It can produce mp4 from independent video and audio tracks. Video track can be provided as a series of still images. I just not sure if specifying single image would work for you.

another option is MEncoder, the problem is the same - you'll need to build it. Or try to find prebuilt one

Answer (score 2):

Are you aware of [AviSynth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AviSynth)? Effectively it allows you to write and/or generate scripts that edit/mix media files. It would go something like ~this:

```
video = ImageSource("file.png")
audio = NicMPG123Source("file.mp3")
AudioDub(vid, aud)
```

I do not remember exact parameters of these functions, plus I only gave the exact names thanks to Google query, but this sample should be really close to actual code you would use.

Answer (score 0):

VLC Media Player ([available here](http://www.videolan.org)) should be able to do the job.

Pressing Ctrl-R after opening the app brings up the Convert menu.

Comment: VLC provides rudimentary conversion, and this task cannot be accomplished with VLC because you cannot specify a still image for video track.

Comment: ubuntu 14.04 here. VLC does nothing.